# JavaScript pCloud API call to fetch userinfo gives an error

Tags: javascript, json, api, cloud, pcloud

While calling the api from JavaScript

This HTTP request works fine `https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo?username=xxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxx`

In the below code I want to call via JavaScript

```
var user='email loggin';
var password='password of pcloud';

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

$.ajax
  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '{}',
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password)); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert('Working Fine'); 
    }
});
```

**output in console**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo?{}](https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo?%7B%7D). Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

If someone can provide a solution or enhance the code.

Comment: it is a CORS request, beforeSend is causing the problem

Comment: can you fix it @AdamWolski

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @radbrawler edit the code providing your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the username and password in the `data` field and remove the "beforeSend" part. For more information and examples, you can check out the pCloud Javascript SDK: https://github.com/pCloud/pcloud-sdk-js

Here is working example (a bit shorter):

```
$.getJSON("https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo", {
  username: "***", 
  password: "***"
}, function() {
  alert("working fine"); 
});
```

Comment: it alerts even if the credentials are wrong.Not Working